# Get item and subsequent item based on a property of the first one

Tags: json, batch-file, jq, data-partitioning

I have an event-log file generated by a third-party tool that I cannot change. So, this log file is a huge JSON array where odds elements contain metadata and the pairs contain the body message associated with the meta-data. I want to be able to split the file depending on the metadata, agglomerating the information by subject in different files.

I am working on this project on windows and I am trying it using a batch file and JQ.

Basically the array looks like this:

```
[
  { "type": "abc123"},
  {"name":"first component of type abc123"},
   { "type": "abc123"},
  {"name":"second component of type abc123"},
  { "type": "def124"},
  {"name":"first component of type def124"},
  { "type": "xyz999"},
  {"name":"first component of type xyz999"},
  { "type": "abc123"},
  {"name":"third component of type abc123"},
  { "type": "def124"},
  {"name":"second component of type def124"},
  { "type": "abc123"},
  {"name":"fifth component of type abc123"},
  { "type": "abc123"},
  {"name":"sixth component of type abc123"},
  { "type": "def124"},
  {"name":"third component of type def124"},
  { "type": "def124"},
  {"name":"fourth component of type def124"},
  { "type": "abc123"},
  {"name":"seventh component of type abc123"},
  { "type": "xyz999"},
  {"name":"second component of type xyz999"}
  ...
]
```

I know that I only have 3 types, so this is what I am trying to archive is create a file for each of them. something like:

First file

```
{
  "componentLog": {
       "type": "abc123",
       "information": [
          "first component of type abc123",
          "second component of type abc123",
          "third component of type abc123",
          ...
       ]
     }
}
```

Second file

```
{
  "componentLog": {
       "type": "def124",
       "information": [
          "first component of type def124",
          "second component of type def124",
          "third component of type def124",
          ...
       ]
     }
}
```

Third file

```
{
  "componentLog": {
       "type": "xyz999",
       "information": [
          "first component of type xyz999",
          "second component of type xyz999",
          "third component of type xyz999",
          ...
       ]
     }
}
```

I know that I can separate the metadata with this

```
jq.exe ".[] | select(.type==\"product\")" file.json
```

And then I try to math the `index`.But index just returns the index of the first item that contains the select statement... So I don't know how to solve this...

Comment: How big is "huge"?  Can you read the JSON file into memory (e.g. `jq empty file.json`)?

Comment: @peak It will be around 5Gb file, so memory is not an option. I am tiding with JQ because AFAIK it does stream of the file for me.

Comment: @shellter thank you for the feedback, but I didn’t understand what do you mean with pare sample data down...

Comment: If the log file is too big for memory, then chances are one of the output files is also too big for memory. If that is the case, what is the point of creating such a large file with a single JSON entity?  Why not partition the log file into three, each with a stream of JSON entities?

Comment: @peak another component will upload those files and convert it inputs for elastic search. I don’t have control of the full workflow, so I have to give what the other team needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following bash script is a bit messy because it assumes none of the files (input or output) will fit into memory.

If you don't already have access to bash, sed and awk in your computing environment, you might want to consider installing [wsl](/questions/tagged/wsl), [mingw](/questions/tagged/mingw), or some such, or you could adapt the script as appropriate, e.g. using [gawk for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm), or [Ruby for Windows](https://rubyinstaller.org/).

The other main assumption not already embedded in the original question is that it's OK to remove the `log-type*.tmp` files and
overwrite log-TYPE.json for the various values of "type".

Be sure to set `input` to the appropriate input file name.

```
# The input file name:
input=file.json

/bin/rm log-type*.tmp

# Use jq to produce a stream of .type and .name values 
# as per the jq FAQ
jq -cn --stream '
   fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs))
   | if .type then .type else .name end'  "$input" |
 awk '
      NR%2 {fn=$1; sub("^\"","",fn); sub("\"$","", fn); next;} 
      { print > "log-type." fn ".tmp"}
'

for f in log-type.*.tmp ; do
    echo formatting $f ...
    g=$(sed -e 's/log-type.//' -e 's/.tmp$//' <<< "$f")
    echo g="$g"
    awk -v type="\"$g\"" '
      BEGIN { print "{\"componentLog\": { \"type\": " type " ,";
      print "\"information\": ["; }
      NR==1 { print; next }
      {print ",", $0} 
      END {print "]}}"; }' "$f" > "log-$g.json"
done
```

Comment: I note that this answer doesn't appear to be a [[tag:windows]] [[tag:batch-file]]. Are you sure that the answer has taken account of the OP's requirements? It is generally unusual for Windows to carry an `awk` or `sed` executable, and even if they do, their syntax is often slightly different. Are you expecting that they have WSL in Windows 10 or Unix tools available? If so, I'd expect you to mention it. There was no [[tag:bash]] tag attached to this question.

Comment: @peak your answer is useful, but because of the extra stuff that I have to install, I would not consider it the proper answer. Thank you for the time and effort put on trying to help me.

Comment: I think you might have missed the point of my answer. If you have such a large input file, and if you want to use jq, then you will have to use jq in the manner shown. I was just showing all the stuff with awk, etc, to provide guidance for the easy part. As they say, SO is not a coding service.

Comment: I have used this code as a base and translated that to NodeJS. Using writable and readable streamers. For node was https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-jq.